# Functions on a value set.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I define a value set as a set of tagged values, each value tagged with the condition under which it is true,

I use this notation,
$$ [2::x=2, -2::x=-2] $$

and define this to mean 2, if x = 2, or -2 , if x = -2.

A "Value Set" is not actually a set. Instead it is the $\text{vs}$ function applied to a set,
$$ [2::x=2, -2::x=-2] \iff \text{vs}(\{2::x=2, -2::x=-2\})$$

$vs$ is defined by:
$$ v :: c \in S \wedge c \implies vs(S) = v $$

Now consider a function applied to two arguments.
$$ f(x, y) = x y $$

Then if we have two value sets,
$$ s = [1::s_1, 2::s_2, 3::s_3] \wedge t = [-1::t_1, 1::t_2] $$

What is $ f(s, t) = s t $ ?

More generally, what is the expression for a function applied to two value sets.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying the two value sets takes every value from the first set and multiplies it by every value from the second set,
$$ s t = [1::s1,2::s2,3::s3] [1::t1,-1::t2] $$
$$ = [1::s1 \wedge t1, -1::s1 \wedge t2, $$
$$ 2::s2 \wedge t1, -2::s2 \wedge t2, $$
$$ 3::s3 \wedge t1, -3::s3 \wedge t2]$$

The general formula is
$$ f(vs(S), vs(T)) = vs(\{f(s_v, s_v)::t_c \wedge t_c | s_v::s_c \in S \wedge  t_v::t_c \in T\}) $$

**Derivation**

Let:
$$ f(vs(S), vs(T)) = vs(R) $$
then:
$$ s_v::s_c \in S \wedge s_c \implies vs(S) = s_v $$
$$ t_v::t_c \in T \wedge t_c \implies vs(T) = t_v $$
The conjunction of the pre-conditions implies the conjunction of the implications:
$$ s_v::s_c \in S \wedge t_v::t_c \in T \wedge s_c \wedge t_c \implies vs(S) = s_v \wedge vs(T) = t_v $$
$$ \implies f(vs(S), vs(T)) = f(s_v, t_v)$$
But for the set $R$ we need,
$$ r_v::r_c \in R \wedge r_c \implies vs(R) = r_v $$
By comparing the expressions,
$$ r_v = f(s_v, t_v) $$
$$ r_c = s_c \wedge t_c $$
where:
$$ s_v::s_c \in S \wedge t_v::t_c \in T $$
Giving:
$$ f(vs(S), vs(T)) = \text{vs}(\{f(s_v, t_v)::s_c \wedge t_c|s_v::s_c \in S \wedge t_v::t_c \in T\}) $$